# Dynamic MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a dynamic sql query that compares my `cat` column to whatever the user entered in a form. The idea is that I will be able to take a dynamic array of values and then compare them to the `cat` column. This is what I tried to do:

```
// Loop to get the array of values from form
$get_arr = $_GET;
foreach ($get_arr as $get) {
    $var = "AND cat LIKE $get";
}
// SQL query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items
WHERE title LIKE 'this'
AND description LIKE 'that'
'%$var%'";
```

It doesn't work -- `$var` always show up blank. What would the solution be?

Comment: debug from the beginning, `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: The parse error doesn't help.

Comment: Right now, you're assigning the `$var` variable to the last `$_GET` element only. You are aware of this, right? And, your code is also vulnerable to SQL-injections, in case you didn't know that.

Comment: @Dagon I've already done that, `$_GET` prints as expected. For example, if I were to just echo out `$get` while in the `foreach` loop, it would print all of the values of the array. The following code works perfectly `$get_arr = $_GET; foreach ($get_arr as $get) {echo $get;}`

Comment: @Max I realize that the code is full of security holes, but I just want to get the idea down and then sanitize the inputs.

Comment: i only know what you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems.

1. You're not escaping the input, so you're subject to SQL injection or syntax errors.
2. You need to put quotes around the `LIKE` parameter.
3. You're overwriting `$var` each time through the loop instead of appending to it.
4. You're not putting any spaces around the expression.
5. You're putting `%` around the whole `$var`, it should be inside the `LIKE` parameter.

```php
foreach ($get_arr as $get) {
    $get = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $get);
    $var .= " AND cat like '%$get%'";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM items
        WHERE title LIKE '%this%'
        AND description LIKE '%that%'
        %var";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really helped me out! Just a note, your missing a semicolon on the 3rd line, it should be `$var .= " AND cat like '%$get%'";` and on the last line, you missing the `$` sign. But thanks again